# How to improve performance of LINQ query to get many fields from a table

Tags: performance, linq

Suppose, I have a table called Accounts which has information like

- bool isManaged,
- double CurrentTotalBalance,
- double CurrentManageableBalance,
- AccountDetails AccountDetail table,
- around 20 fields and 5 different tables

I want to write a query that can select only the field that I need not all of the tables as it reduces my performance.

Currently, I have something like this,

This is just a sample code, but not the working code.

```cs
var accounts = await _context.Accounts
    .Include(x => x.Plan)
    .Include(x => x.AccountDetails)
    .Where(x => x.Plan.Id == 123)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Then I am going, over the accounts list and getting the required results.

It works great for smaller plans but when I have larger plans it loads so many accounts.
So, is there a way to get data from it,
I was thinking something like this,

This is just a sample code, but not the working code.

```cs
var accounts = await _context.Accounts
    .Include(x => x.Plan)
    .Include(x => x.AccountDetails)
    .Where(x => x.Plan.Id == 123)
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        PlanAssets = x.Sum(x => x.CurrentTotalBalance),
        PlanParticipants = x.Accounts.Count,
        OutsideAssets = 123,
        ManagedParticipants = x.Where(x => x.IsManaged == 1).Count()
     })
    .ToListAsync();
```

But the problem with this is I am getting a list of each account. I want to sum up all the `CurrentTotalBalance` in the accounts table.

Is there a way to get the list of those fields which are required only from the accounts table and query them? I am having a performance issue. Any recommendation to improve the performance would be appreciated.

Comment: *Then I am going, over the accounts list and getting the required results.*, your attempt is incorrect,  so better show code which calculates data correctly.

Comment: The query doesn't match the Account class you described. For example, where is `Account.Accounts`? Are you showing actually running code?

Comment: This is just a sample code, not the working code. Thank you